# Locale issue in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, locale

I have this problem with locale on my Linux Mint Debian (LMDE). How can I fix this?

```
cj@linux ~ $ locale

locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=\(null\)
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="(null)"
LC_NUMERIC="(null)"
LC_TIME="(null)"
LC_COLLATE="(null)"
LC_MONETARY="(null)"
LC_MESSAGES="(null)"
LC_NAME="(null)"
LC_ADDRESS="(null)"
LC_TELEPHONE="(null)"
LC_MEASUREMENT="(null)"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="(null)"
LC_ALL=
```

Would this cause any problems for programs and applications ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The `export`, `locale-gen` and `dpkg-reconfigure` method.

Depends on what “locale” you want set, but this works for me when clearing up similar issues on Ubuntu 12.04 which is Debian-based just like Linux Mint. In these examples I am using `en_US.UTF-8` but be sure to change that to match your actual desired locale settings.

First, run the following `export` commands:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then run `locale-gen` like this:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

Then run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` like this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Reboot your machine and it should all be cleared when it comes back online. Check the output of `locale` which should now be something like this:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

#### The adding a `LC_ALL` value to `/etc/environment` method.

Another idea is that you can just set the global locale in this file:

```
/etc/environment
```

By using `sudo` and your favorite editor; I prefer to use `nano` but feel free to use whatever text editor you want to use:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

And then just adding this value to the bottom of that file:

```
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Reboot or logout and login again and that should work as well.

Comment: after executing the export commands everything in locale becomes equal to "en_US.UTF-8" but once I reopen the terminal and check locale it's null values and the same persists after reboot

Comment: i tried changing `/etc/environment ` and that worked after reboot. However I found that there was nothing inside the `/etc/environment ` when i opened to change it as you said. Is that supposed to be so?

Comment: :-/ Perhaps this is how it used to work. But now on Debian 9.6 `locale-gen` doesn't take a parameter.  Instead it reads `/etc/locale.gen` to get it's list of locales to compile.  You can look at this script yourself to confirm this.